# if x = 3 and z is unassigned, why does z = x-- - --x evaluates to 2?

Tags: c#, javascript

if `x = 3` and z is unassigned,
why does `z = x-- - --x` evaluates to 2?

my professor is lecturing about this at the moment, and I'm currently stuck with this dilemma. Unfortunately, no one can explain why it happens.

Comment: x in post decrement minus x pre decrement

Comment: is this `C#` or this is a `JavaScript`? Choose correct tag, please.

Comment: Duane: The font makes it look weird. Its `x--` (x minus minus) minus `--x` (minus minus x)

Comment: C# or JS? [Unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)?

Comment: very bad practice to have such code lines. There are plenty of other ways to explain the usage of `x--` and `--x` differences.

Comment: Nobody would ever write something like this, I wouldn't use it to explain pre/post decrement, but I'd certainly use it to see if the students really understood the concept

Comment: @Adriano: It's not undefined behavior in JavaScript. It would be in C++, but the question isn't tagged C++. I don't know about C#.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, about this topic the "undefined" word is a **very** bad choice. Actually in C# it is well defined but words like "after" and "before" are pretty meaningless (and parentheses too). Nice post from Eric: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx

Comment: _1 for Steve and Francesco.   Using pre and post in the same expression, especially with single-letter variables, is too close to obfuscation.  If anyone I managed wrote such code in a a deiverable that had to be maintained, I would give them legacy code maintenance as punishment, possibly their own code from a year ago.  A month of that will surely cure such practices.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

on x--, x = 3, and after that it's 2.
on --x, x = 1, because substraction (from 2) is done beforehand.

Therefore, 3 - 1 = 2.

Comment: plz refine your answer... i still didnt get

Comment: Just curious: does C# guarantee the order in which the expression is evaluated? How do we know that post-decrement happens first?

Comment: @torrentialcoding Because yes, it "guarantees" that. It's just the way it works, really. Prefix is defined to be done Pre-operation and Postfix is defined to be done Post-operation.

Comment: @torrentialcoding about ordering: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa691322

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov Thanks. From the MSDN article you linked to: "Operands in an expression are evaluated from left to right." That answers my curiosity.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the order of operations, illustrated for better understanding:

- **x**-- - --x Hold value of x (lets call it tmpA). tmpA is 3.
- x**--** - --x Decreases x. It is now 2.
- x-- - **--**x Decreases x. It is now 1.
- x-- - --**x** Hold value of x (lets call it tmpB). tmpB is 1.
- x-- **-** --x Performs substruction from calculated values. 3 - 1 = 2.

The `-- prefix` means the decrement will be done before evaluating the expression and the `postfix --` means the decrement will be done after evaluation the expression.

Comment: @ Yorye: I modified the last paragraph to (I think) make it more clear. Your latest edit wipes that out. If that was intentional, no worries, but if not you might look at the diff and restore the edit.

Comment: I was actually editing it at the same time to code the `--prefix` and `postfix--` which I think is fairly understandable. I wasn't at all trying to ruin your edit - and I REALLY liked your first one - I didn't know you could use basic HTML tags, which got me out of that ridiculous *'s and -'s situation. I didn't think that your last edit's sentence structure was very understandable, but I will be happy if you edited my answer again so you can get your credit for your improvements :)

Comment: @ Yorye: No, if you didn't think it helped, let's leave it. Good answer, I just wish we could use color because the bold doesn't quite do it. (I completely fail to see the reason for the downvote.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the support :) I'm pretty sure that with the bolds here, the parenthesis in the other answer, and other's explanations, the OP will easily understand that line of code, which is in the end the purpose. Thanks again!

Comment: Interestingly, a little algebra shows that this works for all (reasonable) values of `x`. `(x) - ((x-1)-1)` = `(x) - (x-2)` = `x - x + 2` = `2`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget By reasonable you mean in a fair distance from the edges of int.MinValue and int.MaxValue? Hehe, yes. Turns out that X - (X - 2) is always 2.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, its pretty simple:

let's add brackets:

`z = ( x-- ) - ( --x )`

^^ this is how compiler sees your code after tokenizing.

Compiler evaluates equation (right part) from left to right

Now,

`x--` is equal to POP the value of x and then decrement it and PUSH back value into a memory. Ok, lets do it:

Current value of X is 3, decremented is 2 - so, in equation we'll get 3, but X will contain new value 2.

`--x` is equal to decrement X value and then POP this value into equation. Let's do it:

Current value of X is 2 (because previous operation decremented it), and now we want to decrease it once again. 2-1 = 1, got it.

Now, back to whole equation: `z = (3) - (1) = 2`.